# Cygwin X Server configuration

Tags: cygwin, xterm

I remember a few years back, I was able to edit some shell script and then create a shortcut to it, so that anytime I needed an xterm I just used to click on the shortcut which would start the X Server and starts an XTerm client.

it used to be called startxwin.bat or startxwin.sh or something like that.
I used to edit that file and add a command like 
xterm
to the end of the file

anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scripts are gone now.  To start X, you have to run startxwin.exe.

For me, I have a shortcut to the following in both my QuickStart and my StartUp:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe
```

This will then execute whatever's in your `.startxwinrc` file, which you can make your choice of terminal.

You'll get the X menu in the lower right-hand corner.  You can configure the contents of that by editing your `.XWinrc` file.

Comment: You can just have `xterm &` to start a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `startxwin` which is both a Cygwin script and should be in your Windows "Start->Programs-> X server" menu.  I think the file you're thinking of editing is $HOME/.startwinrc, where you can add clients. I think you also need to make sure you have a window manager, something like WindowMaker (wmaker.exe)

If you're primarily running Cygwin X Clients, then the cygwin X server probably makes the most sense.  If you're running clients from UNIX/Linux, it may be easier to run [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/). This is basically a port of the Cygwin XServer code to run as native Windows using mingw.

Comment: thanks for your tip, I now configured my startxwin and it works fine (I also added a command line argument to get the clipboard working as well)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Cygwin, but suggest you look into http://andlinux.org. It is similar to Cygwin (Linux integrated with Windows) but is much easier to install, maintain, and use.

The X server starts automatically. Bring up a terminal (from the desktop shortcut), type `xeyes`, and it just works...

Comment: andlinux setup is moren than half a gig! that's way too much for what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com) terminal instead, which offers xterm-compatible terminal emulation with a native Windows UI, i.e. it doesn't require an X server. Installing it through Cygwin's [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe) creates a start menu shortcut in the Cygwin folder.